# RabbitMQ dapr error when publish to topic topic_name in pubsub pubsub : channel not Initialized

Tags: docker-compose, rabbitmq, publish-subscribe, dapr

I am using dapr rabbitmq pubsub to publish and subscribe the events.

It is Woking fine with cloud end points but getting error in local setup

RabbitMQ dapr error when publish to topic topic_name in pubsub pubsub : channel not Initialized

I am setting up rabbitmq from docker-compose. Yaml

Do i need to give any additional configuration?

In pubsub yaml file, when I placed cloud url it is working, but if replaced localhost:5672 , getting error

### pubsub.yaml

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: pubsub
spec:
  type: pubsub.rabbitmq
  version: v1
  metadata:
  - name: connectionString
    value: "amqps://guest:guest@localhost:5672"
  - name: durable
    value: true
  - name: deletedwhenunused
    value: true
```

### docker-compose.yaml

```
  icertis.pss.services.rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management-alpine
    container_name: rabbitmq-local
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5671:5671"
      - "5672:5672"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
```